# CSS: Links float past headerbar?

Tags: css, header, hyperlink, floating

Demo: http://www.mindtale.com/test.html

I'm pretty new to CSS so I am probably using the wrong code for something in here. I am trying to have a website than can resize to any screen size but at the same time, I want the links I have, Portfolio and Contact, to be permanently placed so it will stay on the headerbar instead of floating off to the left or right beyond it. How could I fix this?

Thanks for the help! :D

test.html

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"> 
<title>Mindtale Test Home</title>
</head>

<body>




<!-- Header -->

<div id="headerlogo">
<a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png"></a></div>

<div id="headerfill"></div>
<div id="header"></div>

<div id="headerlink1">

<a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
</div>

<div id="headerlink2">
<a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
</div>


<!-- Content -->
<div id="content">
<h2>A random heading</h2>
<p>Content Placeholder ... </p>
<p>Content Placeholder ... </p>
<p>Content Placeholder ... </p>
<p>Content Placeholder ... </p>
<p>Content Placeholder ... </p>
<p>Content Placeholder ... </p>
<p>Content Placeholder ... </p>
<p>Content Placeholder ... </p>
<p>Content Placeholder ... </p>
<p>Content Placeholder ... </p>
<p>Content Placeholder ... </p>
<p>Content Placeholder ... </p>
<p>Content Placeholder ... </p>
<p>Content Placeholder ... </p>
<p>Content Placeholder ... </p>
<p>Content Placeholder ... </p>
<p>Content Placeholder ... </p>
<p>Content Placeholder ... </p>
<p>Content Placeholder ... </p>
<p>Content Placeholder ... </p>
<p>Content Placeholder ... </p>
<p>Content Placeholder ... </p>
<p>Content Placeholder ... </p>
<p>Content Placeholder ... </p>
<p>Content Placeholder ... </p>
<p>Content Placeholder ... </p>
<p>Content Placeholder ... </p>
<p>Content Placeholder ... </p>
<p>Content Placeholder ... </p>
<p>Content Placeholder ... </p>
<p>Content Placeholder ... </p>
<p>Content Placeholder ... </p>
<p>Content Placeholder ... </p>

<h2>A random heading</h2>
<p>Content Placeholder ... </p>
<p>Content Placeholder ... </p>
<p>Content Placeholder ... </p>
<p>Content Placeholder ... </p>
<p>Content Placeholder ... </p>
<p>Content Placeholder ... </p>
<p>Content Placeholder ... </p>
<p>Content Placeholder ... </p>
<p>Content Placeholder ... </p>
<p>Content Placeholder ... </p>
<p>Content Placeholder ... </p>
<p>Content Placeholder ... </p>
<p>Content Placeholder ... </p>
<p>Content Placeholder ... </p>
<p>Content Placeholder ... </p>
<p>Content Placeholder ... </p>
<p>Content Placeholder ... </p>
<p>Content Placeholder ... </p>
<p>Content Placeholder ... </p>
<p>Content Placeholder ... </p>
<p>Content Placeholder ... </p>
<p>Content Placeholder ... </p>
<p>Content Placeholder ... </p>
<p>Content Placeholder ... </p>
<p>Content Placeholder ... </p>
<p>Content Placeholder ... </p>
<p>Content Placeholder ... </p>
<p>Content Placeholder ... </p>
<p>Content Placeholder ... </p>
<p>Content Placeholder ... </p>
<p>Content Placeholder ... </p>
<p>Content Placeholder ... </p>
<p>Content Placeholder ... </p>
</div>

<!-- Footer -->

<div id="footer">
Mindtale &copy; 2013
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

style.css

```
html { 
height:100%; /* fix height to 100% for IE */
max-height:100%; /* fix height for other browsers */
background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; /* add background image */
-webkit-background-size: cover; /* fix height for other browsers */
-moz-background-size: cover; /* fix height for other browsers */
-o-background-size: cover; /* fix height for other browsers */
background-size: cover; /* fix height for other browsers */
}

/* Header */
/* -------------------------------------------------- */



div#header {
z-index:3;
position:fixed;
background: url(images/header.png) no-repeat center;
height: 102px;
top:0px;
left:0px;
width:100%;
padding: 0px;
}

div#headerfill {
z-index:4;
position:fixed;
background: url(images/headerfill.png) repeat-x;
height: 98px;
top:0px;
left:0px;
width:100%;
padding: 0px;
}

div#headerlink1 {
font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
font-size:90%;
z-index:4;
position:fixed;
top:55px;
left:18%;
color:#999;
padding: 0px;
}

div#headerlink2 {
font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
font-size:90%;
z-index:4;
position:fixed;
top:55px;
left:78%;
color:#999;
padding: 0px;
}

div#headerlogo {
z-index:5;
position:fixed;
top:30px;
left:42%;
color:#999;
padding: 0px;
}

/* Content */
/* -------------------------------------------------- */

div#content {
position:fixed;
width:100%;
color:#222;
top: 70px; 
bottom: 0; 
left: 0; 
right: 0;
padding: 25px;
overflow: auto;



font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;

}


/* Footer */
/* -------------------------------------------------- */

div#footer {
position:fixed;
bottom:0px;
left:0px;
width:100%;
color:#999;
background:#333;
padding: 8px;
}
    enter code here
```

Comment: post some of your html and css please, so we can help you

Comment: All updated. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a fiddle for you where I have rebuilt your HTML and CSS and you can see it working (couldn't resist). http://jsfiddle.net/David_Knowles/2y7U5/1/

You'll see there is a lot less code.

The Main pointer I will give is that you would be wise to make more use of the Cascade in your styles.
Hence CSS = Cascading style sheets. It's the key to efficient front-end coding. Nest your HTML more too :-) (less styles need then).

```
div id="headerlogo">
    <div id="headerfill">
        <div id="header">
            <a href="portfolio.html" id="headerlink1" >Portfolio</a>
            <a href="index.html"> <img src="http://www.mindtale.com/images/logo.png" alt="Mindtale"> </a>
            <a href="contact.html" id="headerlink2" >Contact</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Content -->
<div id="content">
   <h2>A random heading</h2>
   <p>Content Placeholder ... </p>
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: I was trying the rebuilt version in Safarii and the background doesn't show up anymore, but it works fine in Chrome. Any ideas for a Safarii fix?

Comment: Also, is there any way to get the logo down about 20px?

Comment: Repositioning logo can be done in two ways; with margins or with positioning, using 'top' i.e. #header img {top:20px; position: relative;}

Comment: As to safari background image issue, the sytax was wrong for the background. Corrected now: http://jsfiddle.net/2y7U5/3/

Comment: Thanks Timidfriendly! You're amazing! :D